# Reload page on checkbox event

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using MVC 3 and I have a checkbox: `@Html.CheckBox("mycheckbox", myparam)`

I'd like to refresh the page when the checkbox is checked/unchecked.
How can I do that?

Comment: are you sure you want to refresh the page and not submit the form or indicate the checkbox change in other way ? if so, clarify your question

Comment: I agree with rouen, are you sure you want to refresh the page? the user will lose everything else in the form if you do that. (unless you're saving the values or have no other elements of course)

Answer (score 7):

You will need to use javascript for this. For example you could assign the checkbox an unique id (or class):

```
@Html.CheckBox("mycheckbox", myparam, new { id = "mycheck" })
```

and then use jQuery to subscribe to the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mycheck').change(function() {
        // the value of the checkbox changed => refresh the page:
        window.location.reload();
    });
});
```

Comment: Works fine thanx, Wasnt for a form but to have a new parameter for a filter

Comment: @blop with jquery could show/hide/create new elements without refreshing. just a thought. if this was the solution for you, please don't forget to mark it as the answer